# PL/SQL : How to capture the return value of a statement?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

In the PL/SQL Script I want to capture the number of rows affected with a particular statement, something like

```
BEGIN
   del_count := { DELETE FROM <SOME_TABLE>}
END
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SQL%ROWCOUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#CJACIHFD);

```
BEGIN

   DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES  
   WHERE MANAGER = 10;
   dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows were deleted');

END;
```